# query to create trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named sample_table and its columns are col_a, col_b, col_c.
I am trying to create a trigger in MySQL 5.6 which will update col_c(as concat(col_a,col_b)) on insertion of a row. Query which I have written for this is:

```
create trigger trg_sample_table
after insert on sample_table
for each row
begin
set col_c=concat(col_a,col_b)
end;
```

While running this sql, the error I am getting is:
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the      manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 6.

Could any one of you please help me to create a trigger as I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it a `before insert`. Try this:

```
    create trigger trg_sample_table before insert on sample_table for each row
    begin
       set new.col_c=concat(new.col_a,new.col_b);
    end;
```

You cannot modify the row that you just inserted in an `after insert` trigger. If you want to modify it, it needs to be done in a `before insert`.

Comment: Thank You so much. It is working fine. But while inserting records into that table I am getting an error as: Can't update table 'sample_table ' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.  Could you please let me know what is causing for this?